# phonegap 3 date shows the wrong time

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'd like to get the system-time inclusive the milliseconds. Therefore I use this method to get the system-time:

```
1)
var dt = JSON.stringify(new Date());
```

The dateToString method only returns the date-format with minutes, not the seoonds and milliseconds

```
2)
navigator.globalization.dateToString(
  new Date(),
  function (date) { alert('date: ' + date.value + '\n'); },
  function () { alert('Error getting dateString\n'); },
  { formatLength: 'short', selector: 'date and time' }
);
```

My system-time is 13:07

1. returns

   11:07:44...
2. returns

   13:07

Is it possible to get the seconds and milliseconds from the dateToString method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's Date() has a lot of methods that can help you, like `getMilliseconds()` which will return....the number of milliseconds. There is also `getMinutes`, `getSeconds`, etc. See the full list here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date